# What are the requirements to advance to Public Beta?

Tags: discussion, beta

I have seen that this is the next step and that we have 5 weeks max to do it, but preferably in 1 week. What even are the requirements though? I saw the "How can you help PDLI make it from Private to Public Beta" but it doesn't say the hard requirements. How is a self sustaining community measured? What are the numbers? How do you measure a "healthy volume of high quality questions and answers"? What is considered high quality and what's considered a healthy amount?

Comment: It seems like giving exact numbers can be a bad.  [Are there some specific requirements/recommendations about minimal activity in private beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290459/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an answer [here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290462/295232) by former staff member @TimPost. The first sentence is the most important:

> I hate to put even arbitrary numbers out there because folks tend to fixate on the *numbers* instead of the exercise itself.
>
> The purpose of a private beta is to show that:
>
> - The topic has enough interest to succeed
> - The topic works pretty naturally within the framework of objective Q&A
> - **High-quality, original information about the topic is abundant after a short private beta period.**
>
> It's the third one that requires a bit of interpretation on our part. If a site has 150 questions with answers that just paraphrase Wikipedia, that site has a problem that would probably cause it to (at the least) be held back in private beta for a while longer.
>
> If a site only manages to get 40 questions but they all have fantastic, in-depth answers, then we'd be very inclined to give it more time and see what happens.
>
> If a site only manages to get 30 - 40 questions, and the quality is just not that great, then we'd probably be letting them know that it just didn't work.

I've watched and participated in a couple of private betas, but it's been a while since I've seen one with 130 questions in the first two days. So chances are very high we'll make it to public beta.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, and as someone with genuine but somewhat outdated topic expertise, this site is currently failing #3 big time. It's full of basic, overly generic questions from people trying to rewrite Wikipedia or textbook chapters.

Answer (score 0):

There are not really any public hard numbers, and the approach by SE to new sites has also changed over time, so a lot of information is outdated as well.

It's a bit early to judge, but the volume looks good to me, I don't think that is likely to be an issue here. The volume on private betas tends to drop a lot after the initial burst of activity as you have a limited pool of askers in the private beta.

When I looked at the site initially I was a bit worried about question quality. Quite some posts looked rather superficial and not at the level needed for people actually designing programming languages. It looks a lot better now, there are more in-depth answers that appear to look like there are enough experts here.

I'd focus on quality, I don't think this site will have a volume problem. But I suspect there are potential issues with this topic and bike-shedding. A lot of questions around "why is X designed like Y" allow for easy answers and opinions. That has the potential to lead to bad quality answers easily if unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

I found some information. Not a complete answer though. Information is accurate as of 15:55 5/19/23 UTC. So we need 150 high quality questions to advance, although it is still unclear how high quality is defined. We currently have 162 questions:

> Key

**O**= Open

X+ = Question score of X or higher

AX+ = Answer score of X or higher

> Score above

| Score | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Total | 162 |
| 0+ | 150 |
| 1+ | 144 |
| 2+ | 141 |
| 5+ | 89 |
| 10+ | 20 |
| 20+ | 3 |

> Open and Score above

| Score | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Total | 162 |
| 0+O | 145 |
| 1+O | 140 |
| 2+O | 137 |
| 5+O | 88 |
| 10+O | 20 |
| 20+O | 3 |

> Answer score

| Score | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Total | 162 |
| A0+ | 424 |
| A1+ | 388 |
| A2+ | 309 |
| A5+ | 119 |
| A10+ | 22 |
| A20+ | 1 |

This looks pretty good high quality which I expected is defined as 1 or 2 or more and open.

Next metric is interest and showing that it works with the Q&A format. I have no idea how the latter is shown, but we seem to be doing fine. As to the former, I don't know how interest is measured. However, I would assume Area 51's 10 questions per day would be a good guess. We have 50+ questions per day, so excellent on that front.

Comment: I have taken care of that @mousetail